# Swift 2.0 / Parse - Query not finishing fast enough so app crashes on launch

Tags: swift, uitableview, asynchronous, parse-platform, querying

I've read the relevant questions on the topic, and have been reading up on semaphores, but I haven't grasped them yet.

Here is my issue - I'm loading info from Parse into my tableview, and am using the count of that info to determine how many rows my tableview should have. Below is the tableView function:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return parseObjects.count //parseObjects is obviously an array
}
```

This code keeps returning an error: "found nil value..."

Note: I am calling the query on parseObjects in viewDidLoad(), and it's the first bit of code that should run. I've made several apps using Parse, but don't understand why I'm running into this error. Any code examples / explanation will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `parseObjects` is not yet initialized when your tableview loads. You should have a check on `parseObjects` before trying to access that data. When your asynchronous task completes, call `tableView.reloadData()`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (parseObjects != nil) ? parseObjects.count : 0
}
```

Comment: i see... this is what i am looking for. would you explain what "(parseObjects != nil) ? parseObjects.count : 0" means? im guessing it roughly means "if something isnt ready, dont do it yet ( and wait till it is? )"... thanks again!

Comment: It's shorthand for "if `parseObjects` is not nil, use the count of the parseObjects. Otherwise, use 0. The "wait till it is" part comes when you call `tableView.reloadData` after your fetch is completed (because only then is `parseObjects` populated).

Comment: i keep coming back to this solution and i dont quite grasp it.. specifically, where/when to call reloaddata .... would you post ( or send me ) a really simple example of the async task code and when you call everything ?